# how to add callback to logger of winston node module?

Tags: node.js, winston

I am using winston node module([here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston)).

```
var path = '/logs/mylog.log'
var logger = new(winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)(),
    new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: path})
  ]
});
```

My problem is that, I want to do some coding just after saving this file but i am not getting how can i add the callback function which will execute just after saving log file.
I tried to do:

```
var logger = new(winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)(),
    new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: path},function(){

    })
  ]
});
```

but nothing is happening. 
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`logging`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston#events-and-callbacks-in-winston) event for that:

```
logger.on('logging', function(transport) {
  // check if this was the `File` transport
  if (transport.name === 'file') {
    console.log('logged a message to', transport.filename);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working. But only problem is it's going in infinite loop i.e "logged a message to file.log" is continuously printing n it's never stop. Even return statement is not working. Do you have any idea, why it's happening?

Comment: Are you logging from inside the event handler? Because that would probably cause a loop.